# How can I check if an object is of a certain type at runtime in C#?

Tags: c#, object, types

How can I check if an object is of a certain type at runtime in C#?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the **is** keyword. For example:

```
using System; 

class CApp
{
    public static void Main()
    { 
        string s = "fred"; 
        long i = 10; 

        Console.WriteLine( "{0} is {1}an integer", s, (IsInteger(s) ? "" : "not ") ); 
        Console.WriteLine( "{0} is {1}an integer", i, (IsInteger(i) ? "" : "not ") ); 
    }

    static bool IsInteger( object obj )
    { 
        if( obj is int || obj is long )
            return true; 
        else 
            return false;
    }
}
```

produces the output:

```
fred is not an integer 
10 is an integer
```

Comment: I find the is keyword way underused.   It is so much easier to read!

Comment: Using `is` usually means two casts when one would have sufficed. Which is why it's not used often. Granted, the performance hit is probably imperceptible 99.99% of the time.

Comment: Depending on the requirements either `is' or `GetType()' might be the right solution. See my answer for details about the difference including code.

Answer (score 4):

```
MyType myObjectType = argument as MyType;

if(myObjectType != null)
{
   // this is the type
}
else
{
   // nope
}
```

null-check included

Edit: mistake correction

Comment: You need to store the result of the cast in something.
`MyType myType = myObject as MyType;`, then check to see if `myType` is null; and this doesn't mean `myObject` is a `MyType`, it just means it is assignable to that. Which is an important difference.

Answer (score 3):

The type information operators (as, is, typeof):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d(VS.71).aspx

The Object.GetType() method.

Keep in mind that you may have to deal with inheritance hierarchies.  If you have a check like obj.GetType() == typeof(MyClass), this may fail if obj is something derived from MyClass.

Answer (score 1):

```
myobject.GetType()
```

Answer (score 1):

`obj.GetType()` returns the type

Comment: I'm not sure I ever saw an object in .NET without a type in the past ten years... - So in this case I'd go without the check for null for efficiency.

Comment: He means: `object obj = null; obj.GetType();`, that will throw a NullReferenceException

Answer (score 1):

I can't add comments so I'll have to add this as an answer. Bear in mind that, from the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28VS.80%29.aspx):

> An is expression evaluates to true if
>   the provided expression is non-null,
>   and the provided object can be cast to
>   the provided type without causing an
>   exception to be thrown.

This not the same thing as checking the type with GetType.

Answer (score 1):

Depending of your use case 'is' will not work as expected. Take a class Foo derived from class Bar. Create an object obj of type Foo. Both 'obj is Foo' and 'obj is Bar' will return true. However, if you use GetType() and compare against typeof(Foo) and typeof(Bar) the result will be different.

The explanation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) and here is a piece of source code demonstrating this difference:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp {
   public class Bar {
   }

   public class Foo : Bar {
   }

   class Program {
      static void Main(string[] args) {
         var obj = new Foo();

         var isBoth = obj is Bar && obj is Foo;

         var isNotBoth = obj.GetType().Equals(typeof(Bar)) && obj.GetType().Equals(typeof(Foo));

         Console.Out.WriteLine("Using 'is': " + isBoth);
         Console.Out.WriteLine("Using 'GetType()': " + isNotBoth);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use **switch/case** in c# 7 ([pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching)).

```
string DoubleMe(Object o)
{
    switch (o)
    {
        case String s:
            return s + s;
        case Int32 i:
            return (i + i).ToString();
        default:
            return "type which cannot double.";
    }
}

void Main()
{
    var s= "Abc";
    var i= 123;
    var now = DateTime.Now;

    DoubleMe(s).Dump();
    DoubleMe(i).Dump();
    DoubleMe(now).Dump();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Use the [typeof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx) keyword:

```
System.Type type = typeof(int);
```